# Best known upper bound for Dedekind zeta function on line $\sigma=1$ in the $t$ aspect

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

What's the best known upper bound for the Dedekind zeta function $\zeta_K(s)$ of a number field $K$ for $s=1+it$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$. For example, is something like this
$$\zeta_K(1+it)=o(\log{t}),$$
known, where we allow $o$ to depend on $K$.